# Google Analytics for Android tracking Market keywords?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I do want to implement the Google Analytics for mobile on my android application using the sdk provided on this page 
http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/mobile/analytics/docs/android/

Does someone know, before i start to integrate it, if it tracks the keywords people used on the android market in order to find and install my application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but I don't know how in the moment.

I've seen this guy presenting this: http://www.slideshare.net/NathanMellor/making-money-with-android-apps-8225063

but when I asked him for the library he started talking about something else. :)

Comment: That's interesting. Did you managed to understand how he did?

Comment: He was saying that anyone could have his jar if asked via email, but I asked and never received it.

Answer (score 1):

It does not track the keywords that people use on the Android Market to find your app. What it does is report usage statistics *within* your app, things like how often particular Activities are used or a particular event is triggered.

Comment: Yes i knew the google analytics interface tracks referrals. My question was if the GA interface tracks keywords.

Comment: ...and the first sentence in my post answered your question: it does not.

Answer (score 1):

They do track referrals. See: http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#referrals

Comment: But not for which keywords people used when searching for your application in the Market; only for Market URLs that include the `referrer` parameter.